# Click Counter + Navigation Button at once

Tags: jquery, html, button, click, counter

Please help me to modify this script...

here's the complete code:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
    function clickCounter() {
        if (typeof (Storage) !== "undefined") {
            if (localStorage.clickcount) {
                localStorage.clickcount = Number(localStorage.clickcount) + 1;
            } else {
                localStorage.clickcount = 1;
            }
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = localStorage.clickcount;
        } else {
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Sorry, your browser does not support web storage...";
        }
    }
</script>
</head>
<body link="White">
    <p align="center">
        <p>
            <button onclick="clickCounter();"><span style="font-size:35px;" font face="Face"> Please Click Here to Access QLM </span>
            </button>
        </p>
        <div align="center" id="result"></div>
```

So the question is: How to navigate to other page and use clickCounter() method at once (with the same button)? so it'll not only count the number of click but also direct us to other page.

please help. Thanks in advance ! (and forgive my broken English) >.<

Comment: please post the complete code so that we can help. here you are assigning a value to the "result" element. Where have you written the code to navigate to other page ? what logic are you looking for ?

Comment: @Beauflitz 
I meant to assigning that value not only to "result" but also to navigate to other page (with the same button too) :(

Comment: I have added my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use window.location function

```
<button onclick="window.location='http://www.google.com'">Please Click Here to Access QLM </button>
```

You can specify the url. This is in the case, you don't need the clickCounter() method, but rather navigate to the next page.

Otherwise, you can use this inside clickCounter() method.

```
clickCounter(){

....
window.location = 'http://www.google.com';

}
```

Comment: so how to navigate to other page and use clickCounter() method at once (with the same button)? help me :(

Comment: you can add the window.location inside your function after having all other necessary calculations as per your logic.

Comment: post the complete code and make a jsfiddle if possible.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to use window.location, but more details [at the MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.location)